# caused by out of memory error in android

Tags: android, memory, view, bitmap

I have made a music player. In Player activity I have added a two ImageView. One is for whole background and one is for actionBar icon. When ever I try to play music 3 error occurring.

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

its confusing me because in my real phone (API 17) its running without any problem but in emulator(API 10) the following errors happening. First I throught maybe bitmap is eating the whole memory. I made it static and but no change. I also tried the Picasso library. Still same. The error comming from these line:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0da4d3")));
        actionBar.setElevation(0);
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.customactionbarforplayer, null);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

This is how I am creating the bitmap:

```
private Bitmap getBitMap(Long album_id) {
        Log.e("album id", "" + album_id);
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            final Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, album_id);
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
            if (pfd != null) {
                FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd);
            } else {
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.iconforgrid);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return bm;
    }
```

What Can I do now?

```
04-09 22:08:25.018      612-612/prime.beatbox E/TAG﹕ 0
04-09 22:08:25.028      612-612/prime.beatbox E/TAG﹕ 1
04-09 22:08:25.048      612-612/prime.beatbox E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.widget.PopupMenu', referenced from method prime.beatbox.CustomListViewSongs$2.onClick
04-09 22:08:28.659      612-612/prime.beatbox E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ 2359296-byte external allocation too large for this process.
04-09 22:08:28.719      612-612/prime.beatbox E/GraphicsJNI﹕ VM won't let us allocate 2359296 bytes
04-09 22:08:28.769      612-612/prime.beatbox E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{prime.beatbox/prime.beatbox.Player}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
            at prime.beatbox.Player.onCreate(Player.java:74)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
            at prime.beatbox.Player.onCreate(Player.java:74)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:444)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:349)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:498)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:473)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:112)
            at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:85)
            at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:81)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
            at prime.beatbox.Player.onCreate(Player.java:74)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is the size of you images

Comment: @tyczj it should be very light, because I am loading the music album art image in both Imageview.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10127787/717778

Comment: @TusharTushKhush that does not answer my question

Comment: the images (not imageView's) you are using what are their raw sizes

Comment: I am sorry because I dont know it. I query the album id from the android database. And I use that Id to create the bitmap.

Comment: @tyczj I have added the bitmap function. Can you please check it one more  time?

Comment: @TusharTushKhush still does not answer my question, do you not know how to open and image on your computer and read the dimensions of it?

Comment: @tyczj its 256 * 256